# Count the number of elements in a comma separated string in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have a table where `Col2` is varchar

```
Col1 Col2
1    001,002
2    003,004,005
```

I need to count the number of elements in Col2,and return it, if I do:

```
select --do something here with column-- from table
```

it'll give me:

```
2
3
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So by counting the number of `,`s you have in Col2 and adding 1 to it would give you your answer.  Below I get the length of Col2.  Then I replace the `,`s with nothing and get that length.  I take the first length and subtract the second length to get the total number of commas.  Then simply add 1 to the result to get the total you are looking for:

```
SELECT (LENGTH(Col2) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Col2,",","")) + 1) AS MyCol2Count
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Used this, got ```ERROR:  function length(jsonb) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (LENGTH(recipients) - LENGTH(REPLACE(recipients,","))...
```
Rookie q but does Postgres not support Length?

Comment: Yes PostgreSQL does support the length function. See [**String Functions and Operators**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-string.html). Take a look at this [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/96ae9/5). You need to use the single quotes in Postgre and not the double quotes I show in the answer.

Comment: Whats changed needs to be done to use it in MSSQL ?

Comment: Got the thing to work in MSSQL using `LEN(Col2)-LEN(REPLACE(col2,';',''))`

Answer (score 14):

If it's always formatted like that simply [count the number of commas](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions147.htm#sthref1418) and then add 1:

```
select regexp_count(col, ',') + 1
  from table
```

Answer (score 2):

Linger's answer is incorrect in the special case that Col2 is empty. Instead of yielding a count of 0 you'd get an incorrect count of 1. You can account for this special case with a CASE statement as follows:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Col2='' THEN 0 ELSE LENGTH(Col2)-LENGTH(REPLACE(Col2,",",""))+1 END AS MyCol2Count
FROM MyTable
```

**Edit:** As William has pointed out the empty string WHEN test may be inaccurate if your table is setup to allow NULLs for the column in question. In such a case you'd need to replace the *Col2=''* test with *Col2 IS NULL* (at least in SQL Server).

Note: Apologies, I would have put this as a comment on Linger's answer but I'm not allowed to comment yet.

Comment: In Oracle, `Col2=''` will never be true, because empty strings are just nulls.

Comment: Excellent point. The same can be true in SQL server as well. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.